# How to set write preference when creating a BigQuery Data Transfer through command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a data transfer with `bq mk --transfer_config`

I want the write preference to be `MIRROR`, but I can't find how to set this value through the params?

```
--params='{"data_path_template":"gs://",
"destination_table_name_template":"",
"file_format":"CSV",
"max_bad_records":"1",
"ignore_unknown_values":"true",
"field_delimiter":"^",
"skip_leading_rows":"1",
"write_preference":"MIRROR",
"allow_quoted_newlines":"true",
"allow_jagged_rows":"true",
"delete_source_files":"false"}' \
```

Doesn't work:

BigQuery error in mk operation: Data source definition doesn't define this parameter Id: write_preference

And I can't find any documentation about how to set this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"write_disposition":"MIRROR"`

Seems to work.